# Llenar DataTable jQuery con un JSON ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Resulta que estoy recuperando un JSON de la base de datos usando ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "GetDatosReverse",
            method: "GET",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (respuesta) {
                console.log(respuesta);
            }
    });
```

Recibo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo cual serian estos datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues que recibo estos datos, estoy tratando de hacer esta tabla (como en la imagen siguiente) usando los datos con lo cual quiero mostrar `material` arriba y el resto de datos abajo (como en el ejemplo en este [DataTable Child Rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es por eso que cuando recibo los datos estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo asi:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "GetDatosReverse",
            method: "GET",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (respuesta) {
                console.log(respuesta);


                $('.tablaReversible').DataTable({
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "className": 'details-control',
                            "orderable": false,
                            "data": null,
                            "defaultContent": ''
                        },
                        { "data": respuesta[0]["material"] },
                        { "data": respuesta[0]["material"] },
                        { "data": respuesta[0]["material"] },
                        { "data": respuesta[0]["material"] }
                    ],
                    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
                });




            }
    });

    $('.tablaReversible tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });

    function format(d) {
        // `d` is the original data object for the row
        return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
            '<tr>' +
            '<td>Full name:</td>' +
            '<td>' + "sss" + '</td>' +
            '</tr>' +
            '<tr>' +
            '<td>Extension number:</td>' +
            '<td>' + "sss" + '</td>' +
            '</tr>' +
            '<tr>' +
            '<td>Extra info:</td>' +
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>' +
            '</tr>' +
            '</table>';
    }
```

La tabla al final queda en blanco, que estoy haciendo mal en este codigo??? Gracias

Comment: Al fin lo solucionaste?

Answer (score 1):

1. Primero tienes que obtener el objeto Datatable
2. Luego debes limpiar la tabla ( o destruirla en versiones anteriores a la 1.10)  la tabla
3. Y luego debes recrearla

```
var datatable = $(".tablaReversible").DataTable();

$.get('/LaUrlVaAqui', function(dataArray) {
      datatable.clear();
      datatable.rows.add(dataArray);
      datatable.draw();
});
```

te dejo un ejemplo con la solucion, donde al darle click al boton se cambiaran los registros
https://jsfiddle.net/710uca4d/